# How to reverse-lookup an IP address back to a service?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I work for an organization that has tens of thousands of services deployed to EC2. One of these services is making requests to my server. I have its IP address, but I have no idea who it belongs to. `nslookup` returns an AWS hostname without an indication of who it is assigned to.

Is it possible to look up the name of an EC2 service based on its IP address?

**UPDATE**: If you are going to downvote, please explain why. Otherwise, I can't improve the question.

Comment: What do you mean? PTR?

Comment: I think I would start by7 posting a trouble ticket on their web site. See if they can tell you how to ID the call.

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards No, I mean: given an IP address I'd like to find the name of the service as found at "AWS console -> EC2 Container Services -> Pick a Cluster -> List of Services".

Comment: Although frustrating at times by philosophy and design votes are anonymous and **neither voting [up](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) nor voting [down](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-down) requires any mandatory explanation**. The tooltip that appears when your mouse pointer hoovers over the down button states: *"this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. Also questions attract a down vote when not [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681), not quite [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) or miss details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your servers are in the same AWS account then you should be able to go to the console and paste the IP into the EC2 console. Otherwise you'll need to iterate through all of your accounts to see which has that IP allocated.

Alternatively AWS support might be able to more quickly tell you which account owns that IP so you can shorten your search.

Comment: I am looking at https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?region=us-west-2 and I don't see anywhere to paste an IP into. Where should I be looking?

Comment: Click on 'EC2', then 'instances', then paste it into the bar at the top.

Comment: You get a big cookie. This worked for me. Thank you! :)